# Initializing algebraic data type from list

Tags: list, haskell, algebraic-data-types

I'm a fairly new Haskell programmer and I'm trying to figure out how to get some values into an algebraic data type.

I have a record data type:

```
data OrbitElements = OrbitElements { epoch :: Double,
                                     ecc :: Double,
                                     distPeri :: Double,
                                     incl :: Double,
                                     longAscNode :: Double,
                                     argPeri :: Double,
                                     timePeri :: Double,
                                     meanMotion :: Double,
                                     meanAnomaly :: Double,
                                     trueAnomaly :: Double,
                                     semiMajorAxis :: Double,
                                     distApo :: Double,
                                     period :: Double
                                   }
```

I'm pulling in some info from a text file, which ends up in a list of Doubles.  Is there an easy way to initialize this data type with the list?  I could just call each setter individually but that seems terribly inefficient when I already have all the values in a list.

```
let d = [2456382.5,6.786842103348031e-3,0.7184187640759256,3.394660181513041,76.64395338801751,55.2296201483587,2456457.141012543,1.602144936476915,240.4142797010899,239.7408018186761,0.7233278761603762,0.7282369882448266,224.6987721295883]
let o = OrbitElements
let epoch o = d !! 0
let ecc o = d !! 1
-- and so on
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most direct way is to just do it by hand:

```
fromList :: [Double] -> Maybe OrbitElements
fromList [ _epoch
         , _ecc
         , _distPeri
         , _incl
         , _longAscNode
         , _argPeri
         , _timePeri
         , _meanMotion
         , _meanAnomaly
         , _trueAnomaly
         , _semiMajorAxis
         , _distApo
         , _period
         ]
    = Just $ OrbitElements
          _epoch
          _ecc
          _distPeri
          _incl
          _longAscNode
          _argPeri
          _timePeri
          _meanMotion
          _meanAnomaly
          _trueAnomaly
          _semiMajorAxis
          _distApo
          _period
fromList _ = Nothing
```

However, there is a slightly sexier way, which is to parse them element by element, which is less error-prone and more descriptive of what we are trying to do:

First we define two parsers, one of which requests a new element from the list (or fails if the list is empty), and the second of which matches the end of the list (or fails if the list is not empty):

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

getElem :: StateT [Double] Maybe Double
getElem = do
    s <- get
    case s of
        []   -> mzero
        x:xs -> do
            put xs
            return x

endOfList :: StateT [Double] Maybe ()
endOfList = do
    s <- get
    case s of
        [] -> return ()
        _  -> mzero
```

Now we can define `fromList` in Applicative style:

```
fromList' :: [Double] -> Maybe OrbitElements
fromList' = evalStateT $ OrbitElements
    <$> getElem
    <*> getElem
    <*> getElem
    <*> getElem
    <*> getElem
    <*> getElem
    <*> getElem
    <*> getElem
    <*> getElem
    <*> getElem
    <*> getElem
    <*> getElem
    <*> getElem
    <*  endOfList
```

Comment: Thanks, this confirmed my suspicions, and any answer that starts out 'First, we define two parsers..." is great in my book. :)

Comment: The "by hand" option becomes a littler nicer when combined with [`-XRecordWildCards`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-wildcards): `fromList [epoch,ecc,distPeri,incl,longAscNode,argPeri,timePeri,meanMotion,meanAnomaly,trueAnomaly,semiMajorAxis,distApo,period] = Just OrbitElements{..}`.

Answer (score 11):

A somwhat ugly solution... :-o

Make your type derive `Read`:

```
data OrbitElements = OrbitElements { ... }
                         deriving (Read)
```

Then you can define `fromList` by

```
fromList :: [Double] -> OrbitElements
fromList ds = read $ "OrbitElement " ++ (concat $ Data.List.intersperse " " $ map show ds)
```

Comment: Some silly style notes: `concat` with `intersperse` is the same as `intercalate`. `intercalate " "` is the same as `unwords`. So you could rewrite the second part of your definition as `unwords $ map show ds`.

Comment: Thus, `fromList ds = read $ "OrbitElement " ++ (unwords $ map show ds)`. Perhaps, one needs to write `Data.List.unwords`.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the fact that Haskell is statically typed. No, Haskell doesn't have any such construct.

Let's suppose the language had some way to fill the constructors values from list. Here are some questions to think about:

- What would happen when if the list contained more or less items than required?
- How would you initialize a record whose fields were not uniformly typed?

Answer (score 2):

Algebraic data types are meant to be initialized all at once, not a field at a time as you're doing.  The correct way to do this is:

```
let d = ...
let o = OrbitElements {epoch = d !! 0
                       ecc = d !! 1,
                       distPeri = d !! 2,
                       incl = d !! 3,
                       longAscNode = d !! 4,
                       argPeri = d !! 5,
                       timePeri = d !! 6,
                       meanMotion = d !! 7,
                       meanAnomaly = d !! 8,
                       trueAnomaly = d !! 9,
                       semiMajorAxis = d !! 10,
                       distApo = d !! 11,
                       period = d !! 12}
```

Note that the way you're doing it isn't actually setting any values in `o`.  `let epoch o = d !! 0` defines a function named `epoch` that masks the definition of `epoch` as a field (You should always compile with warnings enabled so that the compiler will catch things like this), and this new function takes any value `o` (not just the `OrbitElements` previously defined) and returns `d !! 0` without doing anything with `o` at all.  If you actually wanted to set or change the `epoch` field of `o`, the correct way to do it would be `let o' = o {epoch = d !! 0}`, which returns a new `OrbitElements` object with its `epoch` field changed.